# Samsung series 5 - RAM Upgrade

Tags: memory, upgrade

I am looking to install an extra 4 GB of RAM on my Samsung Series 5 (NP530U3B-A01US) and have watched videos on YouTube for the installation.  It seems to be too easy to be true in the videos...

For this model, do I just attach the new RAM chip (while power is off) and start the CPU as normal and it's done?... No soldering? No software install?

Clearly, I am inexperienced, but am looking forward to having anyone's help...THANKS!

Comment: RAM is generally a good user-replaceable part and a great introduction to computer hardware upgrades, no soldering required :) See Ramhound's instructions, they look good to me.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

The memory is user replaceable per the user manual and online documentation.

> ### Expandable and upgradable features
>
> A lack of storage or memory can really hamper your ability to work
>   efficiently. The Samsung Series 5 ULTRA includes a HDD (max. 500GB)
>   with over 2x the capacity of other slim models and up to 8GB of
>   upgradable memory to help you multi-task effectively. Plus it includes
>   a full HDMI port and VGA adapter.

[530U3B SERIES 5 Ultrabook Technical Specifications](http://www.samsung.com/ie/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/ultra-portable/NP530U3B-A01UK-spec)

[Memory Upgrade Process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdF556uOwM8)

**Warning**: Without using a paper clip (or similar sized object) to press the button in the "Emergency Hole" to ***cut the battery power*** you can ***fry your motherboard*** by doing what this guy does. ***Please refer to your Samsung manual for more info.***

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is that easy, but:
1) Get the right type of RAM
2) Make sure you are not staticly charged when touching the SoDIMM. (e.g touch something grounded like the heating before you start).

Other than that, remove the cover, clip the SoDIMM in place and replace the cover. Then you are ready to turn on the laptop.

<sup>Nitpick detail: Start the laptop, not start the CPU.</sup>

Comment: I went to the comp shop today and was told that there are multiple types of sodimm rams? something about frequency differences. Is this what you meant by "Get the right type of RAM"?

Comment: 'Many types' is precisly what I meant with 'the right type'. SoDIMM just stands for Small outline DIMM. And like regular DIMMs that is just a form factor. DIMMS come at least in these formats: SDRAM, DDR-1, DDR-2, DDR-3. All of these are incompatible with each other. Within the same type there are also different max rated speeds, latencies etc etc. Usually you can ignore the details as long as the SoDIMM is of the right type (e.g. DDR-2) and of at least the right speeds (e.g. 400MHz for DDR-2 800). Making it more confusing is that the same SoDIMM can also be described as PC2-6400 (bandwidth)

Comment: [This wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) might be useful. Especially [this picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg/424px-Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg.png) which you can use to see what kind of memory is already in the laptop.

Comment: Those links are very useful indeed. I'm just not that familiar with hardware so when the shop guy told me that a SoDIMM RAM has "multiple frequencies", I got confused. I'm familiar with this stuff, just not an expert. So thanks.

Comment: A quick, additional, question though. On @Ramhound's link to the laptop's (I have the same one) spec page, it says `4GB DDR3 System Memory at 1333MHz (on BD 4GB)` and `1 DIMM Slots`. Isn't DIMM different from SoDIMM? A quick google search about the RAM type that this laptop needs seems to take me back here, too.

Comment: A SoDIMM is a Small Outline DIMM. So they are both the same and different. [First picture hit on google: DIMM vs SoDIMM](http://www.coolpctips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/dimm_vs_sodimm.jpg). I think that in this case pictures are clearer than words. :)

Comment: As to DIMM slots. That means it has on SoDIMM slot. SO you will end up taking out the old memory and replacing it with the new SoDIMM. So to install an extra 4 GB of RAM you would take out the old 4GB SoDIMM and replace it with an 8GB SoDIMM.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded my Samsung Series 5 Ultra NP530U3C-A04PL with 8GB DDR3 SoDIMM 1600 MHz.
You should check what type of RAM is specified for your model - I found information for my model at http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP530U3C-A04US

There are at least three very important parameters, you have to know before shopping:

- shape (size). You probably need SoDIMM (aka Small Outline DIMM) (not DIMM - it simply won't fit if you buy wrong size).
- standard: DDR3 (not DDR2 nor DDR1 - I saw on YT that some models even have "ONLY DDR3" printed in big letters inside the laptop)
- frequency: 1600 MHz (not 1333 MHz - I am not sure what happens if you put wrong frequency inside your laptop, but some people speculate that effects can range from deterioration of speed to the lowest common frequency, to totally damaging your laptop)